# SQL Formatter using C#

Tags: c#, sql, parsing

I need to create an SQL formatter in C#. Could anyone point me to some resources on the net? Do I need to implement a full-fledged parser, or is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: Is there an easier way to do it? Can't I format it without parsing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at

[Parsing SQL code in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589096/parsing-sql-code-in-c)

Also hav a look at

[Sql Pretty Printer](http://www.dpriver.com/products/sqlpp/api_index.php)

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, another question I'm stumbling across *much* later, but in case this is useful to anyone else down the line, I've implemented an open-source (AGPL) T-SQL formatter: http://www.architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx

My approach definitely does not involve full SQL parsing (T-SQL is a very complex language, I don't rate my chances of developing and maintaining a complete parser on my own) but rather tokenizing and then identifying major structures in the SQL, by keyword. The result is a partial parse tree with all the formatting-relevant parts broken out.

As noted in answers to the question @astander linked to, there are commercial options for comprehensive SQL parsing, and lots of parser builders out there - but no complete open-source T-SQL parsers than I know of.

Making a parser for simple selects, updates, deletes is straightforward - handling derived tables and subqueries gets a little harder; then OUTPUT clauses, MERGE statements, multi-statement scripts, CTEs, the dozens of DDL statements T-SQL contains, etc: it gets messy.

Comment: This library worked really well for me, and there's a Nuget packed for it now too:  http://nuget.org/packages/PoorMansTSQLFormatter/

Comment: I went to git hub, downloaded the master and used the winform app.

Comment: Be aware that it's licensed under AGPL, so if you use it you have to open-source your own code.

Answer (score 3):

When I am in a crunch and need to make something at least look "formatted", I jump to

http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Answer (score 1):

There is also the SQLinForm SQL beautifier which has a C# API at www.sqlinform.com