# Anyone have a SQL syntax format method?

Tags: c#, sql

Anyone have a good C# method for taking a T-SQL command and formatting it according to some standard? SQL strings are often very ugly and I spend a good deal of time cleaning them up. There's not a good standard format as far as I know, but as long as strings are consistent I wouldn't care too much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944501/sql-formatter-using-c

Comment: Why develop when its already available? You might want to look at http://www.dpriver.com/products/sqlpp/ssms_index.php

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gertd/archive/2008/08/21/getting-to-the-crown-jewels.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use Stored Procedures.

```
//Stored Procedure name is ADDCustomer_sp
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ADDCustomer_sp", con);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter Name = new SqlParameter("@CusName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
Name.Value = TextBox1.Text;
Name.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters.Add(Name);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Use Stored Procedures for what?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstanding. I don't mean that the SQL syntax in my program is ugly and would be helped by putting it behind a sproc. I mean that when a colleague gives me a big SQL statement and says, "Can you tell me how I would do such and such?" I have to spend 15 minutes cleaning up the SQL so I can understand what's going on. It may seem like a nit pick, but I think good and consistent syntax is a big time saver in the work place. I like to put the primary keywords (i.e. SELECT, FROM, WHERE, ORDER BY) on a new line and indent JOINs and extra WHERE clauses.