# Extract parameters like table name, columns etc. from sql string

Tags: python, sql, string, parsing

I need to extract parameters like table names, selected columns and WHERE-statements for a given SQL string in Python 3. Is there a a library, that can do this and could I get an example for my case?
Something like:

```
sql = 'select cola, colb, colc from "someschema"."mytable" where id = 1'
result = sqlparse(sql)
print(result.columns)
>> ["cola","colb","colc"]

print(result.tables)
>> ["mytable"]
```

If the question is not clear: The same question was asked before for C#
[extract column names and table name from any "SQL query" String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479872/extract-column-names-and-table-name-from-any-sql-query-string)

Answer (score 3):

You can use **sqlparser**

The example with table names extraction is here: https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/blob/master/examples/extract_table_names.py

The example with  columns extraction is here: 
https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/blob/master/examples/column_defs_lowlevel.py