# How to parse a SQL Query statement for the names of the tables

Tags: c#, string

I have a string representing a SQL query, and I need to extract the names of the tables from that string. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
```

Would return "Customers". Or

```
SELECT * FROM Customers c, Addresses a WHERE c.CustomerName='foo'

SELECT a.AddressZip FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN Addresses a ON c.AddressId=a.AddressId
```

Would return "Customers, Addresses". Getting more advanced:

```
(SELECT B FROM (SELECT C FROM (SELECT Element AS C FROM MyTable)))
```

Would simply return "MyTable"

(Note, I may have typo'd the queries but you get the idea).

What would be the best/most accurate way of accomplishing this?

Comment: The question "Why?" springs to mind....

Comment: Are you targeting any particular RDBMS/Dialect? There are a few questions on SO about parsing SQL e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589096/parsing-sql-code-in-c Nothing particularly conclusive that I have seen though.

Comment: As for 'why' it is because I am parsing a logfile of queries and displaying the most accessed tables, operations, etc.. not that it should matter :)  As for what am I targeting, it is MS-SQL.

Comment: @esac: it matters. Because sometimes people post questions about specifics of a perceived solution to a problem, and not the actual problem itself.

Comment: Is your logfile a MSSQL logfile?

Comment: @Mitch: it is not. it is output from another tool.

Comment: @esac Given the name, I'm surprised [bash](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/The_case_statement) isn't one of your top tags. Cheers!

Comment: @jpaugh I chose this screen name when I was a wee lad about 25 years ago. At the time there was a new distro of linux just coming on the market named 'Red Hat'. I used Linux almost exclusively for 5 years and then I got a job and entered the business world of Windows computers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to do it, using a commercial utility (sqlparser.com $149, free trial)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using gudusoft.gsqlparser;

namespace GeneralSqlParserTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TGSqlParser sqlparser = new TGSqlParser(TDbVendor.DbVMssql);

            sqlparser.SqlText.Text = "SELECT * FROM Customers c, Addresses a WHERE c.CustomerName='foo'";
            sqlparser.OnTableToken += new TOnTableTokenEvent(OnTableToken);

            int result = sqlparser.Parse();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void OnTableToken(object o, gudusoft.gsqlparser.TSourceToken st, gudusoft.gsqlparser.TCustomSqlStatement stmt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Table: {0}", st.AsText);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it counts 'c' and 'a' as tables, but it would be pretty simple to filter out single character names from your results

I do not use or own this tool, just something I found after some searching...

Comment: It's a good start, although the fact that it picks up 'c' and 'a' are annoying as some are aliased with longer names.

Answer (score 1):

General SQL Parser mentioned by Brian can achieve this in a more accurate way, here is an article for this:

[Get table and column in a complicated SQL script](http://www.dpriver.com/blog/list-of-demos-illustrate-how-to-use-general-sql-parser/get-columns-and-tables-in-sql-script-net-version/)