# What is the best way to evaluate a sql statement in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, dll

What is the best way to evaluate a SQL statement in C# to determine if it does more than just select? - Ie- check if values would be changed (insert, update, delete, modify, or drop) if the statement was later executed.

Any ideas as far as out of the box C# dlls/functions i can use, or is this something I should code myself using string-parsing techniques?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the use-case?  Are you evaluating user-entered ad-hoc queries (that could be malicious), or implementing something internal to an application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589096/parsing-sql-code-in-c-sharp ?

Comment: The user will input the query, and then my code will execute the query (if it is determined to be non-malicious, and does not modify the data source).

Comment: How about letting the user enter a LINQ expression instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use db permissions. Create a database user with read-access only and then, any queries that do anything other than SELECT will fail.

Comment: small caveat - even a `SELECT` can cripple a server... a cross join or 7 should be enough...

Comment: Well - that's the trade off he is going to have to make if he wants to safely check if the query is going to alter data. Trying to parse the SQL will create a world of problems and is just waiting for an injection attack.

Comment: @MarcGravell - yea and I do not see how it can be predicted by anything you would do with the query text

Comment: I don't disagree - I only mention so that the OP is aware of the context

Comment: lolz @Bigfellahull did you decided to down vote me coz I said best answer is in comments by Marc ?

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to use a transaction and then rollback, with obvious limitations (may not work on complex queries, like ones returning multiple result sets with other updates in between, and will not work on queries that use non-rollback commands like DBCC - may want to catch exceptions as well for situations like those):

```
using(SqlConnection sqlConn = new sqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
{
    sqlConn.Open();
    using (SqlTransaction trans = sqlConn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // execute code and see if rows are affected here
        var query = " ... " ;
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);
        var rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (rowsAffected > 0) { ... }

        // roll back the transaction
        trans.RollBack();
    }
    sqlConn.Close();
}
```