# Parsing SQL script for table names

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to parse SQL INSERT statements into object (represented as a text). There is an SQL script file containing:

```
INSERT INTO Document(Id, Name, Description ...)
  VALUES('DC001', 'FOO', 'bar'); 

INSERT INTO DocType(Id, Name)
  VALUES('DT001', 'DOCX');
```

and many more table inserts.

What is the easiest way to parse out Table names (Document, DocType,..)?

Would it be possible with RegEx, if I don't wanna calculate substrings?

```
const string pattern = @"INSERT INTO\s\w";

        foreach (var line in FileContent)
        {
            var a = Regex.Match(line, pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (a.Success)
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex did the trick

```
private readonly IList<string> _tableList = new List<string>();

public const string TableName = @"\s*(INSERT|UPDATE)\s*(INTO|\w+)\s*(\w+)\s*(\(|VALUES|SET)";
public static readonly Regex ValidLine = new Regex(TableName, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var currentTableName = ValidLine.Match(line);
var value = currentTableName.Groups[3].Value;

if (!_tableList.Contains(value))
{
        _tableList.Add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Regex` and probably missing out lots of edge cases you have not considered, look at using a dedicated SQL Parser.

There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589096/1583) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76083/1583) questions for SQL parser for .NET.

Comment: This is all it is, no edge cases. All I need is Table names, Fields and Values in arrays.

Comment: @kayz1 - I am talking about formatting edge cases, different ways of writing the required DML etc.

Comment: I agree with Oded, Regex is the poor man solution, it can and will break eventually, and down the road cause more costs than profit.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem, parsing  SQL files and come up with this universal Parser on Ruby.
It covered all cases and log scan result into file for further review. Can be adjusted for other types too.
[Take R10.rb file from here](https://github.com/dainova/Rubyni.git)