# Regular Expression + C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to parse an sql where I would like to get the where clause of the statement.

Below is the piece of code I have written:

```
string input = "select * from table where x = 5 and abc = 'p' or def = 1  order by col";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"select.*from [a-z]+ where(.*)(?:order by .*)?",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But here the output I get includes the order by statement which I dont want.
I get the expected output if I removed last '?', but the input statement might or might not contain order by.

Expected Output: " x = 5 and abc = 'p' or def = 1 "

can you please correct my regex

Comment: Is the SQL statement restricted or can it reach any level of complexity?

Comment: It is restricted to only where and order by clauses in this case

Comment: then don't use regex at all. use a simple combination of Substring and IndexOf. it will save you a lot of time and trouble.

Comment: you can also try an sql parser instead. [here's a thread about that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589096/parsing-sql-code-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regular expression to parse SQL is a recipe for a king size headache.
try this:

```
string input = "select * from table where x = 5 and abc = 'p' or def = 1  order by col";

string output = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(" where ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)+7, input.IndexOf(" order by "), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase).
```

**Note**: you will need to confirm that your sql actually contains both where and order by clauses, but it's fairly simple to do that

**Note #2**: it might be +6 and not +7, I didn't test the code.

### Edit

It's worth mentioning that my suggested solution also suffers from the same drawbacks that Guillaume pointed out in his answer, i.e if the where clause will contain something like `x = ' order by blabla'` my suggestion will fail as well.
However, it's fairly simple to avoid this, simply change `input.IndexOf(" order by ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` to `input.LastIndexOf(" order by ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`. This way you can be sure to get the actual order by clause of your sql statement.

Comment: nope, c#. they do look alike and I had some Capitalization mistakes but I've fixed them now.

Comment: You should use `IndexOf("str", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` instead of `ToLower` https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms224425.aspx

Comment: @Guillaume You are correct, thanks. I've edited my answer once again according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Add a first group with order clause then another without.

```
string input = "select * from table where x = 5 and abc = 'p' or def = 1  order by col";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"select.*from [a-z]+ where(?:(.*)(?:order by .*)|(.*))",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Regex is not a good SQL parser and it will fail in many cases. For instance :

> select * from table where x = 'order by col'

`order by col'` will be missing from the match.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code to

```
string input = "select * from table where x = 5 and abc = 'p' or def = 1  order by col";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"select.*from [a-z]+ where(.*?)(?=\s+and|$)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

and it will only capture the `where` clause up to the next `and` or the end of the query.

Comment: What if there isn't an `and`? Shouldn't you capture the `and` anyway? Also, you already have `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` so `(?i)` is not needed here, I'm  not sure why you've added it.

Comment: I modified the question to have expected output and your output is only one condition of where clause not all

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
(?<where>(?<=where ).*)(?: order by)
```

Find the group "where" in the match return.
Be sure to match other key words like having or group by.