# Parse SQL INSERT-statement with RegEx

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, regex, parsing

I need to parse SQL to get all:

- Table names after INSERT clause,
- Tables after FROM, JOINs (including CROSS JOIN as comma ',' operator) clauses,
- The same with OPENQUERY or any other subqueries.

Each statement is one-liner SQL, without any extra spaces, comments, or new lines. 
Each query is INSERT-statement.

I have *almost* working regex: https://regex101.com/r/iS2fK9/1.

But it has a problem: regex cathes only first FROM/JOIN statement. Or only last if I apply greedy quantificators.

Ideal result is syntax tree. But simple list of named group will be sufficient.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing SQL code in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589096/parsing-sql-code-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Instead of regex, consider a T-SQL parser: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.aspx