# Matching the regular expression in c# to check cross join query

Tags: c#, sql, regex

I am trying to check cross join by query expression. For example i have the following query.

```
string  query="select t1.c1, t2.c2" from t1,t2";
```

this query will cross join both t1 and t2 table. i have tried the following way to check.

```
string  query="select t1.c1, t2.c2" from t1,t2";

var rx = new Regex(@"\from\s\t1(.*)\,\t2");
if(rx.Match(query)){return "cross-join"}
```

but my regular expression caught error. i couldn't understand where i went wrong because i am new in regex in c#. Is there any other way to check cross join in c#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing SQL code in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589096/parsing-sql-code-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Lets analyze what your regex means:

```
\from\s\t1(.*)\,\t2
```

- `\f` is [form-feed character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break)
- `rom` - `rom`
- `\s` - one whitespace
- `\t` - tab
- `1` - `1`
- `(.*)` - as many characters as possible
- `\,` - comma
- `\t` - another tab
- `2` - `2`

It other words, you added a bunch of escapes that you didn't need and change the meaning of your regex.

```
from\st1(.*)\,t2
```

---

Also note that you have random `"` in your queries:

```
"select t1.c1, t2.c2" from t1,t2"
                    ^
```

Comment: note that the `(.*)` makes the regex practically useless. You probably want `\s*` here. the .* will ensure that `YOUR QUERY ... ORDER BY t1.c1 ,t2.c2` will also be detected as a cross join.

Comment: regex is hardly a good idea to validate cross join presence. counter examples: 1. inner join `select * from t1, t2 where t1.id = t2.id` 2.cross join `select * from t1 cross join t2` 3. cross join effectively `select * from t1 inner join t2 on 1 = 1`

Comment: @ASh, this comment should be in OP's question, not the answer.