# Parse and execute Sql statements from file

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

I am coding a SQL Execution Module, which is part of a medical application.

The module

1. accepts an encrypted `.sql` file name as input. The file will consist of dml statments like insert rows/update rows,comments (Sample below)
2. Decrypts the file
3. Prepares a list of SQL statements and executes, ignoring the comment lines (lines that start with --)
4. Pops up a linenumber in case of error

The method adopted

1. Loading sqlfile and descryption is ok and complete
   Using a simple `File.ReadAllText` and a pre-built decryption module
2. Preparing list is where the module fails. I used this code:

   ```
   string[] dmllines = dml.Split(new string[] { ";\r\n", ";\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   ```

   It causes the execution to ignore the SQL that appears just after a comment due to way it has been split.

The data cannot be split just from linebreak, because there are linebreaks in column values of insert statements. Same goes for semi-colon

- DB: Postgres9.0.4
- Code: .NET 4.0, C#, Npgsql

Any help with a solution is welcome

Thanks

> *EDIT1: I would like to add, There isn't any possibility of using third-party libraries , utilities , even if of postgres.*
>   EDIT2: **I am working on a possibility using regex or just while loop in which to parse char by char**

SAMPLEDATA BELOW

---

> -- Name: activitylog_recordid_seq; Type: SEQUENCE SET; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
>   -- SELECT pg_catalog.setval('activitylog_recordid_seq', 1022, true); INSERT INTO posted (refnum, vdate, contact, totalamount, bankname,
>   staffname, trnmode, trngroup, bookmark, patientid, postedon,
>   statusdate, status, ourbank, chequecarddetail, comment, createdon,
>   editedon, loginid, recordid, sourcetable, sourceid, tallyid, rounding,
>   placed) VALUES (NULL, '2016-02-14 17:51:55', 'AHLCON PARENTERALS
>   (INDIA) LTD', 232.00, '', '', 'Cheques', 'PATIENT RECEIPTS', false, 0,
>   NULL, NULL, 'Cleared', '', '', '', '2016-02-14 17:52:03', NULL,
>   'PPPP', 59, NULL, 0, 63, NULL, NULL);
>   --Insert Imported from DB:00319 INSERT INTO posted (refnum, vdate, contact, totalamount, bankname, staffname, trnmode, trngroup,
>   bookmark, patientid, postedon, statusdate, status, ourbank,
>   chequecarddetail, comment, createdon, editedon, loginid, recordid,
>   sourcetable, sourceid, tallyid, rounding, placed) VALUES (NULL,
>   '2016-02-14 18:04:48', 'AHLCON PARENTERALS (INDIA) LTD', 400.00, '',
>   '', 'Cash', 'PATIENT RECEIPTS;', false, 0, NULL, NULL, 'Cleared', '',
>   '', '', '2016-02-14 18:04:50', NULL, 'admin', 60, NULL, 0, 64, NULL,
>   NULL); INSERT INTO printed (donorname, referencenum, baggageid,
>   campname, receipttype, qty, units, receiptdetail, storestaff,
>   verifiedby, verifiedon, isunsuitable, receiptdate, unsuitablecomment,
>   comment, createdon, editedon, loginid, recordid, qtyissued,
>   qtybalance, expiry, barcode, donorref, barcodedonor, bloodadditives,
>   licenseref, source, attributes, category) VALUES ('', NULL,
>   'B31399040', 'C131 BLUD', 'Blood', 1200.0000, 'mg/Ml', 'AB_Positive',
>   'HELLOO', 'PALS', '2015-06-30 19:03:52', false, '2015-06-29 19:03:52',
>   '', NULL, '2015-06-30 19:05:10', '2015-07-03 12:15:33', 'PPPP', 4,
>   200.0000, 1000.0000, '2019-06-30 19:03:52', NULL, 'd753', NULL, 'Sodium Citrate (dihydrate)....2.63g Citric Acid
>   (monohydrate)...0.299g Dextrose (monohydrate).......2.55g Monobasic
>   Sodium Biphosphate (monohydrate).0.222g', '', '', NULL, NULL);

Comment: Good formatting is your friend. Use it.

Comment: Why not splitting based on ';'?

Comment: You'll need a full-fledged SQL parser in order to properly do this, as you can also have multi-line comments and so on.

Comment: If you can't use 3rd party libs, then this won't be a simple problem to crack, and it will likely be a constant source of bugs. I'd advise you to reconsider.
Char by char should work ok - remember where comments start and end, where strings start and end, and split by semi-colon only where you are outside strings and comments.

Comment: I'd start by creating a sed script. Anchoring on `; INSERT INTO ` ,and maybe `-- SELECT ` and inserting '\n' inside these patterns will probably get you within 99%. And do the rest by hand. (but maybe sed is already too *third party* for these c# kids? )

Answer (score 1):

You should consider spawning [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html) externally to import from file. You should be able to send the info via stdin to `psql`, rather than writing to an actual file on disk - since you mentioned the input data is encrypted.

The output from `psql` can be caught and given back to the user.

Parsing SQL should be done by a specialised parser. As an alternative to `psql`, try looking at using a library that can do this for you, such as the [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework).
See [Parsing SQL code in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589096/parsing-sql-code-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

try this.If you have a query with one or more GO statements you will have to split the script to separate all queries and execute them one by one

```
var fileContent = File.ReadAllText("query.sql");
var sqlqueries = fileContent.Split(new[] {" GO "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var con = new SqlConnection("connstring");
var cmd = new SqlCommand("query", con);
con.Open();
foreach (var query in sqlqueries)
{
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: This is Postgres, not SQL Server.

Comment: thanks again, i am merging two answers, urs and one above . anyway it is weekend and hope to  post a solution soon

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a hack, but for something simple (Select/insert/delete/update) could work:

```
string pattern = "(SELECT|INSERT|DELETE|UPDATE|--)"; //ADD HERE THE SQL VERBS YOU NEED
string[] result = Regex.Split(sqls, pattern).Where(s => s != String.Empty).ToArray<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < result.Count(); i += 2) 
{
     if (!result[i].StartsWith("--"))
     {
           Console.WriteLine(result[i] + result[i + 1]);
     }
}
```

I'm sure this can be improved, but you get the idea. And it works with your sample data

Comment: thanks again, i am merging two answers, urs and one down below from 'VVN'

Answer (score 0):

You may to try to execute your script using `execute` plpgsql command:

```
do $$
begin
  execute 'create table t (x int); insert into t values (1), (2), (3); drop table t;'; -- Change to your script here
end $$ language plpgsql;
```

or create stored function for it:

```
create or replace function execute_script(in p_script text) returns void as $$
begin
  execute p_script;
end $$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: this application is not using external cmds. otherwise i am familiar with Diagnostic.Process to spawn and capture stdout

Comment: @arvind It is not "external cmds". It is native PostgreSQL code like `select ...` for example. [Executing Dynamic Commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) Using it you can execute SQL scripts without any parsing, PostgreSQL will do it for you :)

Comment: @Albelisto no but  still need psql.exe or other executable to be executed , which means that folder must be under security survelliance,

Comment: @arvind Citation: "_I am coding a SQL Execution Module_". So, the your module can not to execute SQL statements?