# How parse SQL to Datatable or array in c#?

Tags: c#, sql

I have simple sql-query, for example `string sql="select 'a1,a2' f1, 2 f2;"`. How to parse `string` to `object[]` (using sql-syntax rules) without database? May be regex transform can be used.

Comment: @flipchart  Not receive, parse simple without sql-server.

Comment: Is 'a1,a2' a value of the one column?

Comment: @Farid Imranov yes, I could be *split(",")* use, but split obtain wrong result.

Comment: What result you was receive?

Comment: What is desirable result you want to get from this example?

Comment: Are you looking for how to write a SQL parser in c#, as in the question [Parsing SQL code in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589096/parsing-sql-code-in-c-sharp)?  Because that's too broad of a topic for a single stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "select 'a1,a2' f1, 2 f2;";
Regex.Matches(str, "(^|[\\s,\\,]){1}(\\'.*\\'\\s*\\w+|[^\\,^']*)[\\,,$,;]")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value.Split(new[] { ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                            .First().Replace("\'",""))
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, I try `select '1,a2' f1,2 a,'123' a,4, 1` or `select 1 a, 2 b, 3 c` and it's fail, but idea good. I use regex `"\\,(('[^']*[^,]*')|[^,]*)" ` and replace *select* to ','. More: `string str = "select '1,a2' f1,2 a,'123' a,4, a"; foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(str.Replace("select",","),"\\,(('[^']*[^,]*')|[^,]*)")) Console.WriteLine(m.Value.Substring(1));` Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Split` method of string in `C#` like .Split(',')

Comment: Your idea is good, but Split gets  [a1'][a2'][2] and I need to receive [a1,a2][2]

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: Without  database use. I want convert sql-query without table to array.

Comment: then you can use `loop` through the string, find `,` character and if this character is not first use in string then `substring` since to this charcter