# Negative lookahead in Regex to exclude two words

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the following regex:

```
(?!SELECT|FROM|WHERE|AND|OR|AS|[0-9])(?<= |^|\()([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)
```

that I'm matching against a string like this:

```
SELECT Static AS My_alias FROM Table WHERE Id = 400 AND Name = 'Something';
```

This already does 90% of what I want. What I also like to do is to exclude `AS My_alias`, where the alias can be any word.

I tried to add this to my regex, but this didn't work:

```
(?!SELECT|FROM|WHERE|AND|OR|AS [a-zA-Z0-9_]+|[0-9])(?<= |^|\()([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                          this is the new part
```

How can I exclude this part of the string using my regex?

Demo of the regex can be found [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F!SELECT%7CFROM%7CWHERE%7CAND%7COR%7CAS%7C%5B0-9%5D%29%28%3F%3C%3D%20%7C%5E%7C%5C%28%29%28%5Ba-zA-Z0-9_%5D%2B%29&i=SELECT%20Static%20AS%20yo%20FROM%20Table%20WHERE%20Id%20%3D%20400%20AND%20Name%20%3D%20%27Something%27%3B)

Comment: You can't use an [sql parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589096/parsing-sql-code-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: As for the regex, I think you could use `\b(?<!\bAS\s+)(?!(?:SELECT|FROM|WHERE|AND|OR|AS)\b)(?<=[ ^(])[A-Za-z_]\w*`

Comment: I agree with the above suggestion.  Even if we give you a patch for your current regex, it is still very simple and would fail for many other types of queries.  Write/use a parser here for best results.

Answer (score 0):

This excludes the `AS` and gets the tokens you seek. It also handles multiple select values, along zero to many `Where` clauses.

The thought is to use *named* explicit captures, and let the regex engine **know to disregard any non-named capture groups**. (*A match but don't capture feature*)

We will also put all the "tokens" wanted into one token captures `(?<Token> ... )` for all of our token needs.

```
var data = "SELECT Static AS My_alias FROM Table WHERE Id = 400 AND Name = 'Something';";

var pattern = @"
^
SELECT\s+
   (
     (?<Token>[^\s]+)
     (\sAS\s[^\s]+)?
     [\s,]+
   )+                  # One to many statements
FROM\s+
(?<Token>[^\s]+)       # Table name
(
  \s+WHERE\s+
   (
      (?<Token>[^\s]+)
      (.+?AND\s+)?
   )+                  # One to many conditions
)?                # Optional Where
";

var tokens = 
Regex.Matches(data, pattern, 
              RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace // Lets us space out/comment pattern
            | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)        // Only consume named groups.
     .OfType<Match>()
     .SelectMany(mt => mt.Groups["Token"].Captures // Get the captures inserted into `Token`
                                         .OfType<Capture>()
                                         .Select(cp => cp.Value.ToString()))
     ;
```

`tokens` is an array of these strings: `{ "Static", "Table", "Id", "Name" }`

---

This should get you going on most of the cases of what will find. Use similar logic if you need to process selects with joins; regardless this is a good base to work from going forward.