# How can i get the parts of a SQL string using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, parsing

I have an SQL string

```sql
select Id, Name from Order where Id ='8675' and Name ='Test'
```

How can I get the parts of this using C#, i.e. the `from` part, `where` part and `select` part to end up with:

- `select Id, Name`  -----> select part
- `from Order` -----> from part
- `where Id ='8675'` -----> where part

and any other part if required, if they have `group by` etc?

I have tried the following

var str = @"select Id, Name from Order where Id ='8675' and Name ='Test'";

```
        String[] spearator = { "from", "where" };
        String[] strlist = str.Split(spearator,
           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The issue i get now is that it doesnt ignore case , so if there was a From it wont work .
How can i do that ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589096/parsing-sql-code-in-c-sharp

Comment: I have added my attempt to the question

Comment: looping through the characters, replacing to lowercase unless they're in a quote might work, but remember to handle escape characters, and subqueries are even more complex to handle

Comment: Check out the following [parser](https://github.com/bruce-dunwiddie/tsql-parser), there is an example on the wiki page for parsing a select statement.

Comment: Have you tried using [Regex.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#overloads) ?

Comment: @Schmittmuthelm Regex cannot parse context-free grammar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing SQL code in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589096/parsing-sql-code-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] strlist = str.ToLower().Split(spearator,
           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Add ToLower() before Split().